# Vue router for multiple navigations

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, router, vue-router

I am using vuejs router as frontend for my app which is getting deeper and deeper day by day. Now my client has asked me to create a new section for my site which basically is a complete website in its nature. hence will have a different navigation. Now my question is how do i make it happen.

one solution is to use a variable or something to hide the main navigation and show this sub-navigation bar. This doesn't feel neat to me. 
'
I open to any suggestions.

Comment: Can you put the new section on a new page, with its own router?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942188/vuejs-sub-nav-components-outside-of-router-view/45945877?noredirect=1#comment78858208_45945877
You can use the same approach with what you are doing here.

Comment: @exclsr thats what i am asking. can that be done ? how

Comment: I mean, can you serve an entirely different HTML page from your web server? Kind of like treating them like two different apps in two different folders? Would that solve your situation?

Comment: yes thats what i want.. how ? @exclsr